# How to split a row where there's 2 data in each cells separated by a carriage return?

Tags: powerquery

Someone gives me a file with, sometimes, inadequate data.

Data should be like this :

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Name    | Initial   | Age    |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Jack    | J         | 43     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Nicole  | N         | 12     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Mark    | M         | 22     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Karine  | K         | 25     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Sometimes it comes like this tho :

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Name    | Initial   | Age    |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Jack    | J         | 43     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Nicole  | N         | 12     |
| Mark    | M         | 22     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Karine  | K         | 25     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

As you can see, Nicole and Mark are put in the *same row*, but the data are separated by a carriage return.

I can do *split by row*, but it demultiply the data :

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Nicole  | N         | 12     |
|         | M         | 22     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Mark    | N         | 12     |
|         | M         | 22     |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Which make me lose that Mark is associated with the "2nd row" of data.

(The data here is purely an example)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to transform each cell into a list by doing a `Text.Split` on the line feed / carriage return symbol.

```
TextSplit = Table.TransformColumns(Source,
                {
                    {"Name",     each Text.Split(_,"#(lf)"), type text},
                    {"Initial",  each Text.Split(_,"#(lf)"), type text},
                    {"Age",      each Text.Split(_,"#(lf)"), type text}
                }
            )
```

Now each column is a list of lists which you can combine into one long list using `List.Combine` and you can glue these columns together to make table with `Table.FromColumns`.

```
= Table.FromColumns( 
      {
          List.Combine(TextSplit[Name]),
          List.Combine(TextSplit[Initial]),
          List.Combine(TextSplit[Age])
      },
      {"Name", "Initial", "Age"}
  )
```

Putting this together, the whole query looks like this:

```
let
    Source = <Your data source>
    TextSplit = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Name",  each Text.Split(_,"#(lf)"), type text},{"Initial",  each Text.Split(_,"#(lf)"), type text},{"Age",  each Text.Split(_,"#(lf)"), type text}}),
    FromColumns = Table.FromColumns({List.Combine(TextSplit[Name]),List.Combine(TextSplit[Initial]),List.Combine(TextSplit[Age])},{"Name","Initial","Age"})
in
    FromColumns
```